# "Para que" y concordancia de tiempos

Tags: concordancia-verbal

¿Deben los verbos antes y después de "para que" observar las reglas de la concordancia de tiempo? Por ejemplo:

> Ayer, mi madre me dio dinero para que hoy pueda ir de compras.

¿Es correcta esta frase, o se debería escribir "pudiera" en lugar de "pueda" dado que el verbo "dar" está en tiempo pasado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La oración:

- Ayer, mi madre me **dio** dinero para que hoy **pueda** ir de compras.

es un caso no canónico de concordancia temporal que resulta aceptable sólo si la acción subordinada (en este caso, "ir de compras") es posterior al momento del habla, o sea, si la persona aún no ha ido de compras. Si es anterior, debe usarse:

- Ayer, mi madre me **dio** dinero para que hoy **pudiera** ir de compras.

Existe lo que se llama un "doble anclaje" o "doble acceso" que está muy bien explicado [en este artículo](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Tiempos%20-%20Correspondencia%20de%20tiempos.htm).